# Assign user group to group of entries

Tags: users, control-panel, user-groups

In the CP, is it possible to assign a user group to selected entries within a section.

For example, say I have a section called `Events`. Within that section I have a fieldType called `company`.

Can I create a user group called `Company 1` where users within it can only see/edit entries within `Events` section that has its `company` field selected as `Company 1`?

Trying to ascertain if its possible to allow users from multiple companies access to the CP, but heavily restrict what they can access.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It isn't possible to set permissions for individual entries (based on a field value, entry type or any other criteria).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what else you need, you *might* be able to do this with locales.

You would have a `company1` locale, and a user group that had access to only that locale.

Abusing locales in this way is the approved way to do a multi-site Craft install: [Coming to Craft 3: Multi-Site](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-multi-site)